# Providing Android application inside company

Tags: android, google-play, publish

In our company I would like to provide my application for some workers, the options are:

1. via APK - unsafe for phones, complicated updates
2. via GooglePlay - app can be installed and decompiled by "3rd party people", we do not have something special to hide there (yet ;)), as our web service is secured by logging to it first, but we would like to avoid making it fully publish
3. via Google Play as test build - limitation to 100 users
4. via enterprise mobility management (EMM) solutions - we do not have EMM, we would like to avoid creating work profiles on employee devices (these are their private phones, some people are not enough technical to do it, we don't have experience with EMM to deploy it in our company

Is there any way to publish app which will fulfill only few following features:

- app is available to users which I choose, for example by their GMail account or by only known to me link
- automatic updates when there is new version of app
- crash reports (I have Crashlytics so this point may be insignificant)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a service called App47 for this: https://app47.com/

Basically it allows you to install a private app store on people's phones with all of your internal apps. Check it out

There are others like it but that's the one I've been using